# Python 2.7 opening multiple files from non-default directory (for opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, path

I'm using python 2.7 on 64 bit win7 and have opencv 2.4.x.

When I write cv2.imread('pic') it opens pic in my default python path which is `C:\Users\Myname`. But how I will manage to browse different directory to open images? ie `D:\MyPicLib`.

Meanwhile, I do not want to change default directory, because all my python modules are saved in `C:\Users\Myname`. **I just want to manage connecting pictures in `D:\MyPicLib`**

After this part, can you also help me to browse not one but multiple images (in specific format, like just .jpg's in a directory) in for/while loop?

Thank you in advance, the problem seems easy but despite all my effort, I did not find any solution on changing default python path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I recommend looking for some tutorials that show basic os and os.path usage. They are very useful tools. [Here](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/os_module.html) is the first one I found.

```
import os
import cv2

mypath = os.path.join('c:\\', 'asdf', 'jkl')

images = list()
for item in os.listdir(mypath):
    if '.jpg' in item:  # this could be more correctly done with os.path.splitext
        image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(mypath, item))
        if image is not None:
            images.append(image)
```

Comment: it helps, thank you. so we should use os.path.join to access the files. Thanks again!