# Read Multiple images on a folder in OpenCv (python)

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I want to read multiple images on a same folder using opencv (python). To do that do I need to use `for` loop or `while` loop with `imread` funcion? If so, how? please help me...

I want to get images into an array and then processed them one at a time through a loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.7 opening multiple files from non-default directory (for opencv)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312328/python-2-7-opening-multiple-files-from-non-default-directory-for-opencv)

Answer (score 43):

```
import glob
import cv2

images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("path/to/files/*.png")]
```

Comment: this returns empty lists only

Answer (score 14):

This will get all the files in a folder in `onlyfiles`. And then it will read them all and store them in the array `images`.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy
import cv2

mypath='/path/to/folder'
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
images = numpy.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object)
for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
  images[n] = cv2.imread( join(mypath,onlyfiles[n]) )
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import glob
import cv2 as cv

path = glob.glob("/path/to/folder/*.jpg")
cv_img = []
for img in path:
    n = cv.imread(img)
    cv_img.append(n)
```

Answer (score 4):

This one has better time efficiency.

```
def read_img(img_list, img):
    n = cv2.imread(img, 0)
    img_list.append(n)
    return img_list

path = glob.glob("*.bmp") #or jpg
list_ = []`

cv_image = [read_img(list_, img) for img in path]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2
from pathlib import Path

path=Path(".")

path=path.glob("*.jpg")

images=[]`


for imagepath in path.glob("*.jpg"):

        img=cv2.imread(str(imagepath))
        img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)                         
        img=cv2.resize(img,(200,200))
        images.append(img)
print(images)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it without using `glob`, but with using the `os` module instead, since I could not get it to work with `glob` on my  computer:

```
# This is to get the names of all the files in the desired directory
# Here I assume that they are all images
original_images = os.listdir('./path/containing/images')

# Here I construct a list of relative path strings for each image
original_images = [f"./path/containing/images/{file_name}" for file_name in original_images]

original_images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in original_images]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def flatten_images(folder):               # Path of folder (dataset)
    images=[]                             # list contatining  all images
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        print(filename)
        img=plt.imread(folder+filename)  # reading image (Folder path and image name )
        img=np.array(img)                #
        img=img.flatten()                # Flatten image 
        images.append(img)               # Appending all images in 'images' list 
    return(images)
```