# opencv: reading and writing images from folder

Tags: python

I am very new to python and OpenCV. I have around 600 images both in jpg and png format in a folder. I want to read every image and do some processing (let's say edge detection) and want to write those processed images into another folder. I am trying it out with this code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import sys
import time
import os


mypath = "C:\\Users\\Ravi\\dataset\\class_1"

files = [f for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(os.join(mypath, f))]

for n in range(0, len(files)):
    img = cv.imread(os.join(mypath, files[n]))
    laplacian = cv.Laplacian(img,cv.CV_64F)
```

it is giving me this error.

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(os.join(mypath, f))]

AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'join'
```

So my question is how can I read images with different formats and write them with the **same name** into another folder?

Comment: its `os.path.join`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read Multiple images on a folder in OpenCv (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369832/read-multiple-images-on-a-folder-in-opencv-python)

Answer (score 0):

join isn't directly part of the os module its in a submodule called path. So just replace

```
os.join(mypath, f)
```

with

```
os.path.join(mypath, f)
```

Comment: NO it can't be the same error! [see](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/), I don't think you have tried that!

Answer (score 0):

Please change following to:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(os.join(mypath, f))]
```