# cv2.imread does not recognize path

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to load multiples images with cv2.imread, and I also specified the full path in the imageIDname.txt (sth like the ones below):

```
                          'C:/yolov4/coco/images/val2017/000000397133.jpg'
                          'C:/yolov4/coco/images/val2017/000000037777.jpg'
                          'C:/yolov4/coco/images/val2017/000000252219.jpg'
                           ...
```

But it seems cv2.imread cannot open them.
Here is my code

```
b=open('C:/yolov4/imageIDname.txt','r')
for item in b.readlines():
    print(item)
    print(type(item))
    
    original_image = cv2.imread(item)
    original_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

and the error log

```
'C:/yolov4/coco/images/val2017/000000397133.jpg'

<class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:/yolov4/detect.py", line 120, in <module>
   app.run(main)
 File "C:\Users\kaelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
   _run_main(main, args)
 File "C:\Users\kaelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
   sys.exit(main(argv))
 File "c:/yolov4/detect.py", line 44, in main
   original_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\kaelt\Downloads\opencv-4.4.0\opencv-4.4.0\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

However, when i run `cv2.imread('C:/yolov4/coco/images/val2017/000000397133.jpg')` everything is fine.
Well, since I'm gonna run 5000 images, it would be best if I won't have to run this one by one.
Thanks for help!

Comment: does `cv2.imread('C:/yolov4/coco/images/val2017/000000397133.jpg', cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` run ok? your example with the single filepath doesn't include the color, and i wonder if that is related

Comment: I'm pretty sure  with single filepath it runs ok. Thats why I m really frustrated about this. If you need evidence, I can put a single `print()` in this case, but I do not think its neccessary

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369832/read-multiple-images-on-a-folder-in-opencv-python/33371454 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312328/python-2-7-opening-multiple-files-from-non-default-directory-for-opencv.

Comment: Since `print` ends up printing the single quotes, that means that the path strings include them, and thus the paths are invalid. You're basically doing something like `cv2.imread("'C:/yolov4/coco/images/val2017/000000397133.jpg'")`.

Comment: i will show proof when i run single filepath `[[[124 128  77]
  [120 126  64]
  [104 111  57]
  ...
  [ 11  12  14]
  [  9  10  12]
  [ 12  13  15]]

 [[115 131  68]
  [120 136  73]
  [ 94 109  52]
  ...
  [ 13  13  13]
  [ 10  10  10]
  [ 11  11   9]]

 [[115 126  68]
  [117 131  69]
  [ 89 104  45]
  ...
  [  8   6   7]
  [ 43  42  40]
  [ 61  60  56]]

 ...

 [[139 104  74]
  [142 107  79]
  [139 105  77]
  ...
  [ 50  33  25]
  [ 50  33  25]
  [ 44  30  21]]

 [[140 105  73]
  
  ...
  [ 47  29  19]
  [ 50  32  22]
  [ 49  32  22]]]`

Comment: this is the result when i  `print` the function `cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: found the error, `readlines()` returns str with `\n` at the end, i just need to `rstrip()` that. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import cv2

images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(r'C:\yolov4\coco\images\val2017\*.jpg')]

for img in images:
    original_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```